# Looking for a way to parameterize a PSQL interval

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have the following code snippet working as intended in PSQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Puzzle 
WHERE date > current_date - interval '1' year 
  AND date < current_date + interval '50' day
```

I am now running into an issue when parameterizing this in Node.js. My best guess is below, but this returns an error on the `$1`

```
client.query('
SELECT * 
FROM Puzzle 
WHERE date > current_date - interval $1 year 
  AND date < current_date + interval $2 day
', ['1', '50'])
```

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use integer parameters if you rephrase the query a bit. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Puzzle 
WHERE date > current_date - $1 * 'interval 1 year'
  AND date < current_date + $2 * 'interval 1 day'
```

Comment: I personally prefer `make_interval()` in such a situation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Cool. I didn't know that function.